# VPNC modp2048 IKE support

Tags: vpnc

I am having trouble to connect to company VPN via `vpnc` using "IKE DH group 14" (modp2048). The vpnc only seems to support the old `modp1024` algorithm. See config below...

Actually the whole story is - I am using `bitrise.io` as CI and I need it to connect to company VPN. They are using this plugin, [bitrise-step-vpnc-connect](https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/bitrise-step-vpnc-connect), but based on communication with both sides, it is an issue with `vpnc` itself...

When I set "IKE DH group 14" in the config file, the result is:

```
vpnc: IKE DH Group "14" unsupported
```

The only supported algorithm is `modp1024`, but it is broken and not recommended: [Security Recommendations](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/SecurityRecommendations).

Thats why we need the stronger IKE algorithm:

- [IKEv1 Cipher Suites](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IKEv1CipherSuites)
- [5.6.1](https://wiki.strongswan.org/versions/67)

**Config:**

- Local Port 0
- IPSec gateway XXXX
- IPSec ID XXXX
- IPSec secret XXXX
- IKE Authmode psk
- Xauth username XXXX
- Xauth password XXXX
- NAT Traversal Mode cisco-udp
- IKE DH group 14

**Result:**

```
vpnc: IKE DH Group "14" unsupported
```

Comment: 2.5 years and still no answer?  Ubuntu 22 and 23 appear to be missing dh group 14 support in vpnc as of today.

Which means I can't upgrade my ASAs to Cisco's recommended release, because group 5 support is removed in that release.